# Projection of a 3D spherical function to a carteasian axis

Tags: graphing-functions, spherical-coordinates, quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

I have a 3D function defined in a spherical coordinate system $(r,\theta,\phi)$, which is written as a product of a radial function $R_{nl}(r)$ and a spherical harmonic $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ I.e 
$$
 \Psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi) = R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi).
$$
Here $n,l$ and $m$ represent the quantum numbers and $\Psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)$ is a wavefunction, for some context and I only have numerical data for the radial functions. I want to plot the projection of the modulus squared of the wavefunction versus a specific carteasian axis. For example the projection in the z-axis can be defined as 
$$
f(z) = \int\int dxdy~ |\Psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)|^2.
$$
I've been told this is equivalent to writing 
$$
f(z) = \int d\vec{r}~ \delta(\vec{r}\cdot\hat{k}-z)|\Psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)|^2
$$
where $\vec{r}$ is the vector in spherical coordinates and $\hat{k}$ is the unit vector in the z direction. Is there a way to calculate this function of z (also for x and y) using one of the two equivalent forms, without knowing the analytic form of the radial function?

Comment: You can't say "for example" because the $z$ axis plays a special role for the $Y_{lm}$. If you project onto the $z$ axis, the $\phi$ integration will yield $2\pi$ for $m=0$ and $0$ for $m\ne0$. Do you want to do this for all axes or is $z$ enough?

Comment: @joriki I need to do it for all axes. I've found an example of the projection on this [website](http://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/AOs/2p/wave-fn.html). Thanks for pointing out that for the z axis, although that is just the $\phi$ integration, what would the function of $z$ be for $m=0$

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the squared magnitude -- in that case the $\phi$ integration yields $2\pi$ for all $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do it for the $z$ axis to give you the idea; it's also possible for the other axes, but a bit more complicated.

The $z$ axis case is simpler both because, as noted in the comments, the integration over $\phi$ yields $2\pi$, and because in this case we have simply $\vec r\cdot\hat k=r\cos\theta$. Thus after integrating over $\phi$, we're left with

$$
f(z)=2\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm drr^2\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\theta\sin\theta\,\delta(r\cos\theta-z)\left|R_{nl}(r)\right|^2\left|Y_{lm}(\theta,0)\right|^2\;.
$$

Since you don't have $R$ in functional form (I guess you have samples?), we want to perform the integral over the delta distribution in $\theta$, not in $r$:

\begin{eqnarray}
f(z)&=&2\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm drr^2\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\,\delta(r\cos\theta-z)\left|R_{nl}(r)\right|^2\left|Y_{lm}(\theta,0)\right|^2\\
&=&2\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm drr^2\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\frac1r\delta(\cos\theta-z/r)\left|R_{nl}(r)\right|^2\left|Y_{lm}(\theta,0)\right|^2\\
&=&2\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm drr\left|R_{nl}(r)\right|^2\left|Y_{lm}(\arccos (z/r),0)\right|^2\;.
\end{eqnarray}

This you can evaluate numerically using your numerical representation of $R_{nl}(r)$.

The principle applied here that you'll need for the other cases is

$$
\delta(f(t)-z)=\sum_{f(t_i)=z}\frac{\delta\left(t-t_i\right)}{f'(t_i)}\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you, although I think you are missing an $r^2$ in first equation from the metric. I will try the other two cases myself, with the principles you introduced.

Comment: @Free_Apples: Sorry, thanks for catching that. Let me know if you run into trouble with the other two axes; I haven't tried it myself so don't know for sure how much more complicated it will get.

Comment: Come to think of it, it may well be easier to re-express your spherical harmonics along the other axes and then apply this projection than to work out the other projections. The Wigner $D$ function that you need to rotate $Y_{lm}$ is worked out here: http://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/math/wigner.html -- if I'm not mistaken, the only coefficients you'll need are the $d(j,m,m',\pi\,/\,2)$ given at the end of the first section.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Wigner D function, although I think it could be a bit over my head, but i'll give it a go. I've been trying to evaluate the f(z) function numerically for $l=1$, $m=-1$. In this case $|Y_{1-1}(arccos(z/r),0)|^2 = 3/8\pi(1-(z/r)^2)$, and the thinking about the projection onto the z axis it should be zero, however if i've done the integration correctly, I get a parabola. Is projection correct to produce the figure I linked in the previous comments?

Comment: @Free_Apples: I hadn't checked out that link. They don't do any projection; the text says that the plot shows the wave function (by the way, not the square of its magnitude) in the $xy$ plane. Also your expectation that the result should be $0$ for $Y_{1,-1}$ is correct for a plot in the $xy$ plane and wrong for the projection -- so it looks like you're not actually interested in the projection at all? At least one of us is confused here :-)

Comment: My only problem with the projection is that $\int dz f(z) $ should equal 1? Since the wave function is normalised. However, if I've done the integration properly, the integral of f(z) diverges, I'll keep looking into it. With the other two, projections, how will the delta function property generalise to $\delta(\sin\theta\cos\phi-x/r)$? Not sure how comfortable I am with the Wigner D function, as I've never seen it before, but I'll try and look into it. Thank you again for everything so far, I've already learnt a lot.

Comment: @Free_Apples: If I understood correctly, you were integrating $|Y_{lm}|^2$, with no $R$ (or $R=1$). That's not a normalized wavefunction; it's a spherical harmonic normalized over the sphere, extended indefinitely in the radial direction. That its integral over all space diverges is correct. For a normalized wavefunction, you need to multiply it by something like an exponentially decaying radial function.

Comment: @Free_Apples: Regarding the other axes: I have other things to do right now, but I'll be happy to explictly write down the Wigner transformation, and I'll see if I can work out the delta integration approach.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you (Hard to convey ideas with 600 character limit), but  I did the numerical integration for the exact f(z) function, using the data I have from the radial function, for the specific case of $l=1$, $m=-1$ and that function of f(z) diverges. That would be amazing, thanks again.

Comment: @Free_Apples: Above, you wrote that "the integral of $f(z)$ diverges"; here you wrote that "that function of $f (z)$ diverges" (which function of $f(z)$?). Can you describe in more detail what you do and what diverges where? (at $z=0$, or at $z=\infty$, or integrated over $z$?)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the integral of $f(z)$ diverges, when it should be equal to one. To calculate $f(z)$ I've been setting up a vector then numerically integrating the function $r|R_{nl}(r)|^2|Y_{lm}(\arccos(z/r),0)|^2$ for each value of z. The $f(z)$ function is even, and the integral diverges.

Comment: @Free_Apples: It's hard to comment on that when I don't know your $R$. Can you provide the values? Or is it similar to some closed-form $R$ that we could consider instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25840/discussion-between-free-apples-and-joriki).